# How to use Azure Speech Service in Bot Framework Web Chat

Tags: botframework

I am using Bot Framework Web Chat and I correctly setup a front-end for the user to chat with my bot.  I am trying to enable speech for it, I try following the tutorial here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat-speech?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

The problem I have is I try to use Azure Speech Service, I setup my service correctly, and I set the key.  But I am not sure where to get the CognitiveServices?  The tutorial doesn't specify where to get it.

Here is my code:

```
<div  id="bot"/>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
<script>

    const speechOptionsRemote = {
        speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({ subscriptionKey: '...' }),
        speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
            gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
            subscriptionKey: '...',
            voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'
        })
    };

    BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: '...' },
        user: { id: 'WebChat' },
        bot: { id: '...' },
        resize: 'detect',
        speechOptions: speechOptionsRemote,
        showUploadButton: false
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    var header = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header");
    header[0].innerHTML = "<span ><p align='center' >My Bot</p></span>"
</script>
```

It complain that CogntiveService is not found when I navigate to the page.  Where do I get it?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. What exactly are you missing here? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: The issue is that Bing Speech has been deprecated, and there is not currently a way to use a Cognitive Services Speech key with WebChat.  The WebChat team will be releasing an update soon, allowing pony fill with Cognitive Services instead of Bing Speech.

Comment: https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js

Comment: WebChat now has support for Bing Speech keys as well as Cognitive Services Speech keys: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/06.a.cognitive-services-bing-speech-js/index.html https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample is using v3 of Webchat, which is now deprecated, see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/v3#microsoft-bot-framework-web-chat). There is a v4 of BotFramework-WebChat on the GitHub repository, the update has been a few days ago.

So when in your code your are downloading `cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js`, it is the v4: that explains why it can't found `CognitiveServices`: it has been refactored.

For using Cognitive Services Speech in the v4, have a look to the dedicated sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/speech-cognitive-services-bing-speech

Comment: The issue is that Bing Speech has been deprecated, and there is not currently a way to use a Cognitive Services Speech key with WebChat.  This will be fixed soon, but right now it is broken.

Comment: I thought that Bing Speech will be stopped only in 2019 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/home). But here @EricDahlvang, isn't there a problem with the `latest\botchat.js` version which is pointing to v4?

Comment: The Bing Speech service will continue to function, but users cannot create new Bing Speech keys.

Comment: I assumed the OP created one on time as he said `and I set the key`, but I may be wrong. He also added that the error was `It complain that CogntiveServices is not found`, so looking at the code I read the `new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer` from the v3 readme and look at the v4 sources where the behavior has changed

Comment: I spoke with William Wong, the maintainer of WebChat, about this yesterday.  He is aware of the issues (a cognitive services speech key will not currently work with CognitiveServices.js, and users cannot create new Bing Speech keys).

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1137 refers to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/SpeechToText-WebSockets-Javascript/issues/85 (which is a deprecated library currently used by webchat)

Comment: Good to know! Thanks Eric

Comment: Very helpful everyone, I will try it tonight and see if I can get it to work using v4!

Comment: @Bill you got it working ? I am having issues running the github sample.

Comment: Sorry I haven't worked on this project for last little while

Comment: This issue is tracking progress to support Cognitive Services speech in WebChat: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1336